# What is the best method for creating an API using MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using mvc3 and I want to create an API with the site.

MVC makes it really easy to return json from the controller which I know how to do.

I want to use a subdomain for the api something like http://api.mydomain.com

I have a few questions

1. Do I create an area for api or just place the controller and model in the root?
2. How can I point to the subdomain so the url is api.mydomain.com not mydomain.com/api
3. What is the best way to version the api? do I just create a new controller for each version e.g. V1Controller,V2Contoller etc etc

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would suggest using the new WCF Web APIs rather than MVC3 for that sort of thing. http://wcf.codeplex.com

Comment: Are you looking to also have an interactive web app on this site or just a service architecture?

Comment: MVC3 is *much* easier to use than WCF, and you have much more control over requests and responses. Save yourself the hassle and use MVC.

Comment: @xixonia Have you tried the new WCF bits? They're very easy to use and much more lightweight than a full MVC3 app for an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently used ServiceStack, I really like working with it, you should take a look

http://www.servicestack.net/